# Finding the asymptotics of $\sum_{k=1}^n a^k k!$? Note that $a > 0$.

Tags: summation, asymptotics, factorial

There's no way to use integration method in this case. I also tried to use Stolz–Cesàro theorem, but couldn't find right $y_n$. What method should I use?

Comment: as a tends to infinity or as n tends to infinity?

Comment: i guess none tends to infinity @Assaultous2

Comment: what do you meean? he wrote "asymptotics"

Comment: oh sorry , i read the question wrong

Comment: @Assaultous2, n, of course.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer: thats exactly the point, or at least, you're right as n tends to infinity. That's why the question is about asymptotics.... how fast does it diverge? is essentially the question

Comment: I'd say the asymptotic behaviour as n tends to infinity is a^n n! , essentially the last term, since the terms in the sum grow so quickly that even the sum of all the previous terms is small compared to the last one ( factorials grow faster than exponentials) ... however, i cannot yet rigorously prove this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it! Ok, so here we go:

First, factor $a^n n!$ out of the sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a^k k! = a^n n! ( 1 + \frac{1}{an} + \frac{1}{a²n(n-1)} + \cdots  ) $$

It is clear that the inner bracket tends to 1 as n $ \to \infty $, so the asymptotic behaviour is indeed given by $a^n n! $

Comment: This would benefit from a proof that the inner bracket does tend to $1$ as $n \to \infty$, but I think the idea is right.  +1

Comment: @ Yes,Antonio Vargas, I realised after posting that even though all the other terms besides one in the inner bracket tend to zero, since there are more and more of them as n tends to infinity, they must not necessarily vanish, so it is not as "clear" as I said.